# google photos application timeline feature using the year of images when they created

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, photo, timeline

I want to implement the google photos application timeline feature in the recycler view in which we can show the year of images as a label while scrolling as shown in below image.

[image: google photos year timeline feature]

Can anyone help in this or implemented something like this.

Comment: Please show what you have already tried and what specific issues you are running into. This is not a "how to" forum.

Comment: I am currently trying to implement that but I have no idea of implementing this.I got to know that it is known as date-scrubber feature.

Comment: Agree with dharms. Your first clue is to inspect similar libraries, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/timusus/RecyclerView-FastScroll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by simply adding a new Linear-layout on top of the recyclerview with a child textview in the layout and then by calculating the height ratio(as per the count of images per year) with respect to the total height available.Also considering the minimum height of textview to 100 if the ratio is too small.

```
private float getEffectiveHeight(float totalHeight, float count, float totalCount) {
    if (count * (totalHeight / totalCount) < 100)
        return 100;
    else
        return count * (totalHeight / totalCount);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Would be nice if you could share a rough guideline on how you did this.

Comment: I have described my approach in description of answer..@bompf

Comment: I think he was talking about the timeline :) 
Good one BTW ! I'm also interested